# Disable spell-checking in Whatsapp?

Tags: macos, macos-mojave, whatsapp

Is it possible to disable spell-checking in Whatsapp for macOS?

I’m running Whatsapp version 0.3.4480 on macOS Mojave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I could fix this:
Type something incorrect. When the red line appears, right-click > Spelling & Grammar > Correct Spelling Automatically.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

**WhatsApp doesn't have a dictionary of prediction so choose the Below method**

**Step 1:**
Launch System Preferences from the Apple menu.

**Step 2**
Select the "Language & Text"

**Step 3**
 Click on the “Text” tab and uncheck the box next to “Correct spelling automatically”

Enjoy the day,

Comment: Hi @irfan.codility! What macOS version are you referring to? I guess Apple has changed those settings because in Mojave there is no icon in System Preferences labelled ”Language & Text”. There’s a screenshot available in Mojave’s documentation: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh15217/10.14/mac/10.14

However, if I go to Keyboard and then Text, there is an option called ”correct spelling automatically”. It’s not checked though! Still WhatsApp redlines word that it considers to be incorrectly spelled. Could it be a bug in Whatsapp perhaps...?

Comment: This will disable the spell-checking for all apps instead of just Whatsapp as the question asked for.